# How to disable dock counter in Thunderbird 52?

Tags: thunderbird

Does anyone know how to disable the unread message counter on the icon (see attachment) in Thunderbird 52.4.0 (64-bit)? It was possible in earlier versions, now I can't find this option anywhere.

[counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMKhn.png)